Time travel (with barn / stable)
Trying to identify this movie (or tv series?)
All I know is this:

Involves some kind of time travel
One of the characters is visited by someone in his barn?
There is some kind of time travel that goes on in this barn.

I know that's not a lot to go on.
Update: Not back to the future. I think the guy (in the past?) is visited by a girl from the future and ends up going with her or something.

I think it might have been Timestalkers but I need to watch the movie again to confirm.


Ok so after watching this on youtube, this is definitely the movie I was thinking of.

It could be The Barn from the TV-series Haven. It is somewhat related to time travel/science fiction and has some very complicated story lines involving the female lead character. 


Not bad, but I watched this as a kid. So I'd say 20 years ago? Maybe 15.

Its a little bit of a long shot ... is this Back To The Future (1985)?
The first time Michael J Fox's character Marty McFly travels in time, he goes back to 1955 and crashes the De Lorean time machine in a barn.  The farmer (Otis Peabody) and his family investigate the crash and think that he's an alien invader - because of the strange UFO like car and his hazmat suit.


No sorry. I'll update my question as BTFF so clearly the obvious answer given the information I gave.

Could it be Looper ?

It involves time travel.
There is a scene where the main character hides out in a woman's barn, and he stays with her. 



Nope, way too new. I think I'm right with Timestalkers.

@monkjack, if you know the time frame in which you saw the movie and/or when it might have been made, you should add that to your question.

I did add something as a comment, but I'll add it to the question yes.
